# $G$ Group, $H< J$, and $\forall J < G \Rightarrow H \subset Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup such that $H$ nontrivial is a subgroup of J, for all $J$  nontrivial subgroup of $G$. Show that $H  \subset Z (G)$.
Thanks

Comment: The center is a subgroup, which may be trivial or not.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo But davide, how does that help

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but we can take $J=Z(G)$.

Comment: As long as it's nontrivial

Comment: It helps us have a better discussion if, after stating the problem, you tell us what you have tried. [Even if nothing you've done has quite worked out, or if you can only state some things which you suspect might work.] Welcome, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the class equation would be helpful. I think

Comment: What happens if G si finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\,\,H\rlap{\,/}{\subset} Z(G)\,\Longrightarrow \exists\,x\in G\,\,s.t.\,\,hx\neq xh$ , for some $\,h\in H\,$ . Now take a closer look at $\,\langle x\rangle\,$

Answer (score 1):

By your hypothesis, the intersection of all nontrivial subgroups is nontrivial, and the subgroup $H$ is contained in this intersections.  In particular, $H$ is contained in every cyclic subgroup $C$ which is not 1.  So if $x$ is any non-identity element, we have $H \subseteq \langle x \rangle$. This means that every $h \in H$ is a power of $x$, so it commutes with $x$. Since this works for any $x \neq 1$, we're done.

**Corrected according to Matt E's comment:**

We can actually deduce much more from this situation.  If $G$ contains an element $x$ of infinite order, then $H$ is contained in every subgroup of $\langle x \rangle$, and so $H$ is trivial. Therefore, $G$ is a torsion group.  Then since any two cyclic subgroups of $G$ of prime order intersect trivially, $G$ can only contain one such subgroup, and so we can conclude that $H \cong \mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: Dear Dane, Two remarks: firstly, an infinite group need not contain a copy of $\mathbb Z$; it could be an infinite torsion group (e.g. $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$).  Secondly, if $G$ *does* contain a copy of $\mathbb Z$, then $H$ is contained in the intersection of all subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, therefore is trivial. Regards,

Comment: @MattE Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: G need not be equal to H, indeed G need not be finite or abelian. You are right that H definitely has to be Z/pZ though.

Comment: @JackSchmidt thanks